# Request send from Android Mobile is get no any response on server

Tags: android, web-services, rest, httprequest, httpresponse

I am new in android world and server side programming for mobile Application. I am getting a problem:- when from any android mobile send me a request in form of url , then my server (Apache tomcat) did not find any response about that request.

I am writing following code in client side(Android Mobile):-

```
public static void requestForDepartment()
{
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String iName = null;
    String iprice = null;
    String idPrice = null;
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("storeId","s0001"));

    try {
        System.out.println("inside server try 1");
        // start - line is for sever connection/communication
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new
          HttpPost("http://192.168.1.3:8080/xybuy/rest/webservices/requestDepatment");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // end - line is for sever connection/communication
        InputStream is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "
                + e.toString());
    }
}
```

192.168.1.3:8080 is my endpoint. This is my web.xml file at server side

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"    version="2.5">
  <display-name>FirstProject</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  <welcome-file>index2.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>
        com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.servlet.ServletAdaptor</servlet-  class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>ServletAdaptor</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/REST/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The actual payload can be JSON or XML. And server is restful webservices.

Comment: REST != rest, could it be the reason ?

Comment: I don't think the REST is the reason......

Comment: how do you know if it is json or xml ? (given that you don't specify it in the request headers ?)

Answer (score 0):

1) Try adding headers to your request, say

```
httppost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

java adds some headers by default, but sometimes that is not enough.

2) Does it work if you run this code in java project from your local PC?

Comment: Server side coding is working. I am using RESTfulwebservices. the response is json object

Comment: What means "my server (Apache tomcat) did not find any response about that request". Do you mean that webserver found no data, which corresponds to "storeId","s0001"?

Answer (score 0):

@Eugene is right but your question is completely unclear. You say its xml and json. How can that be ? If its xml, then you need a "application/xml" as content-type, if its json then your content-type = "application/json".